# NameValueList in JSS to field type

Tags: jss

I'm building a GraphQL query to return back an item and its fields.  One field is `NameValueList` - I can just return it as a string and cast it to an interface

the layout service returns it like this:

```
"myNameValueList": {
  "value": "key1=1&key2=0"
}
```

My interface looks like this:

```
interface MyFields {
  id: string
  name: string
  myNameValueList: string
}
```

Is there a way I can return it that's not like a query parameter? is there a way I can use nextjs field to map this instead of a string?  so it ends up being something like:

```
interface MyFields {
  id: string
  name: string
  myNameValueList: { [key: string]: string }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NameValueList` Field, stores value in the form of querystring which gets delivered as it is in layout service. So, in order to get the data in a more meaningful structure you can customize the `Field Serializer` for NameValueField.

The first step is to create a custom serializer by inheriting `Sitecore.LayoutService.Serialization.FieldSerializers.BaseFieldSerializer` and overriding `WriteValue` Method:

```
public class NameValueListSerializer : BaseFieldSerializer
{
    public NameValueListSerializer(IFieldRenderer fieldRenderer) : base(fieldRenderer)
    {
    }
    protected override void WriteValue(Field field, JsonTextWriter writer)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)field, nameof(field));
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)writer, nameof(writer));
        try
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            string range = field.Value;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(range))
            {
                string[] ranges = range.Split('&');
                if (ranges != null)
                {
                    foreach (string dropdownpair in ranges)
                    {
                        string[] pair = dropdownpair.Split('=');
                        writer.WritePropertyName(pair[0]);
                        writer.WriteValue(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(pair[1]));
                    }
                }
            }
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error(ex.Message, typeof(NameValueListSerializer));
        }
    }
}
```

Now, implement the class by inheriting `Sitecore.LayoutService.Serialization.Pipelines.GetFieldSerializer.BaseGetFieldSerializer` and overriding `SetResult` Method:

```
public class GetNameValueListSerializer : BaseGetFieldSerializer
{
   public GetNameValueListSerializer(IFieldRenderer fieldRenderer) : base(fieldRenderer)
   {
   }
   protected override void SetResult(GetFieldSerializerPipelineArgs args)
   {
     args.Result = (IFieldSerializer)new NameValueListSerializer(this.FieldRenderer);
   }
}
```

Now, the last step is to patch our custom resolver and we need to make sure that we patch it before `GetDefaultFieldSerializer` processor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <group groupName="layoutService">
        <pipelines>
          <getFieldSerializer>
            <processor patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.LayoutService.Serialization.Pipelines.GetFieldSerializer.GetDefaultFieldSerializer, Sitecore.LayoutService']" type="Sandbox.GetNameValueListSerializer, Sandbox" resolve="true">
              <FieldTypes hint="list">
                <fieldType id="1">name value list</fieldType>
              </FieldTypes>
            </processor>
          </getFieldSerializer>
        </pipelines>
      </group>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Now, instead of the `querystring` we will get the object of `key-value` pairs.

**Credit:** https://gauravarorasb.medium.com/sitecore-headless-services-custom-field-serializer-for-namevaluelist-field-da2b51280cd7

Hope it helps!

Comment: your answer looks like an exact copy of https://gauravarorasb.medium.com/sitecore-headless-services-custom-field-serializer-for-namevaluelist-field-da2b51280cd7 . You should clearly state at the beginning that it's not your code and link to the original article. Otherwise it's a plagiarism and that's not welcome on Sitecore Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks, @MarekMusielak. I do try to always add credit/reference links to the original author of the article. I did miss this time. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

solution by Sumit was great but just posting an alternative solution for those who want to do it in typescript rather than adding a custom field serializer:

```
function getValues(myValue: string) {
  const myValueStringArray = myValue.split('&')
  const myObj: { [key: string]: number } = {}
  myValueStringArray .forEach((pair) => {
    const [key, value] = pair.split('=')
    const parsedValue = parseInt(value)
    if (!isNaN(parsedValue)) {
      myObj[key] = parsedValue
    }
  })
  return myObj
}
```